# How to deal with big files containing lots of coordinates with OpenLayers v2.13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, openlayers, openstreetmap, geojson

I have on OpenStreetMaps map with a vector layer containing all USA's states shapes.

These coordinates are stored in a MongoDB database, and when the user wants to display the map, my server (running under Node.js) computes a GeoJSON file with these coordinates and sends it to the client.

The problem I have is that this file can be very big (~20 Mo) because these shapes are very detailed so there are a lot of coordinates, even for one state.
Even when gzipped the file remains big (~3-5 Mo). I can't send such a big file, for bandwidth and Javascript memory considerations.

So I'm looking for a scenario that would allow me to send all these coordinates with a reasonable bandwidth and browser memory usage.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider to *render* the file instead? I.e. [setting up a rendering server](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/), importing your file and creating tiles which already contain this information? That way you don't have to send any coordinates at all, just the tiles.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your answer

This seems to be a cool idea. But all documentation I could find about mentions only the use of postgreSQL to import the data. And I use MongoDB :(

Comment: MongoDB is quite lacking in spatial functionality currently, compared to Postgis, supporting only basic intersects, contains and near functions. However, you could write a polygon simplification algorithm quite easily in MongoDB and serve up smaller version of the polygon, according to zoom level.

Comment: Ok, I've just installed PostgreSQL, PostGIS and Mapnik to give it a try. Data from OpenLayers is importing, I think this will take a long time.
I was looking into Mapnik documentation, and nowhere I found a way to render a vector layer. Am I missing something, or did I misunderstand the use of Mapnik ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a new question, ideally at https://gis.stackexchange.com :)