# Viewing .tif file n the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, tiff

I'm using react to build a web app to view images, videos and maps.

The map files are in .tif format and some of them are huge one is 350+ mb. I don't know much about .tif and how they work.

Is there any library to load and render such files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `OpenLayers` library for .tif files, see [examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geotiff-reprojection.html) for more info.

Comment: can you explain how it will handle a file of 350+mb?

Comment: see for dealing [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843135/how-to-deal-with-big-files-containing-lots-of-coordinates-with-openlayers-v2-13] (large files)

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog.html

Comment: @BR75 is there any way I can set the initial zoom level and also zoom limits? when using new View({}) we can set it there but here we are getting the view from .getView() and the problem is that i'm getting a .tiff file that is too much zoomed in

Comment: @ZulluBalti sure, the view has setter for zoom https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#setZoom

Comment: @BR75 I'm using GeoTiff as the source and to get the view I'm calling source.getView() here to set the view parameter I'm doing something like this 
  `source.getView().then(viewConfig => { 
    viewConfig.zoom = 0; 
    viewConfig.showFullExtent = true; 
    return viewConfig
});`

Here i don't want to set the zoom level to -negative value as for some .tif files it does display correctly. Any way to make it zoom out to the fullest for everything?